# Shiny automatically visit each screen and evaluate its reactive values

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that has multiple tabs/screens (`tabItems` to be precise).
Each screen has a couple of charts that are constructed using `reactive()` data objects. As the data objects can take some time to construct, I have cached them using memoise (where the cache is saved to disk, note the memoisation is not shown as it is beside the question). Once the app is run the cache will fill automatically but I want to prefill the cache for the default values to have a better user experience for the first usage (there is some potential filtering going so therefore some waiting times will occur later on anyways on but that is beside the question I think).

That is, ideally I would like to have an option that automatically visits each screen and thereby evaluating each reactive value (and thus filling the cache). In the example app below the memoisation/caching is mocked by printing to the console.

## MWE

A simple app with two screens would look like the example below.

Now I want to be able to visit tab 1 and tab 2 automatically from a separate R script to force the evaluation of the reactive values (eg in this case this would print the "Evaluating Reactive Element in Server id ui1" + ui2)

```
library(shiny)

# 1) Create a module that will be used multiple times
mod_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    h1(paste("Tab with id", id)),
    plotOutput(ns("plot"))
  )
}

mod_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      data <- reactive({
        print(paste("Evaluating Reactive Element in Server id", id))
        data.frame(x = 1:10, y = cumsum(rnorm(10)))
      })
      output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(data()$x, data()$y))
    }
  )
}

# 2) create the main app functionality
main_ui <-  navbarPage(
  "Example App",
  tabPanel("Tab 1", mod_ui("ui1")),
  tabPanel("Tab 2", mod_ui("ui2"))
)
main_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mod_server("ui1")
  mod_server("ui2")
}

shinyApp(main_ui, main_server)
```

which (with the terminal output at the bottom) would look like this
[image: picture of the app with the terminal below]

## Attemps

One possible solution is to use `testServer` to test the screens, but this requires that the script needs to be updated once a new reactive value is created or its name changes.

Eg with the app above, I could use the following

```
# repeat for each module-server
testServer(mod_server, args = list(id = "ui1"), {
  a <- output$plot
  # list other reactive values/plots here...
})
#> [1] "Evaluating Reactive Element in Server id ui1"

testServer(mod_server, args = list(id = "ui2"), {
  a <- output$plot
  # list other reactive values/plots here...
})
#> [1] "Evaluating Reactive Element in Server id ui2"
```

Ideally I would like something like the following

```
start_app_and_evaluate_all_reactive_values(main_server)
#> [1] "Evaluating Reactive Element in Server id ui1"
#> [1] "Evaluating Reactive Element in Server id ui2"
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see where the data is memoised in your example.  Perhaps you can find a way to achieve your goal without actually simulating clicks on the tabs.  But you'd need to show the memoisation to get help in that direction.

Comment: Since reactives are lazy, maybe use observers (which are eager) and then save to a reactive value.

Comment: You are correct, I didn't show the actual memoisation here (its another abstraction in the question that I feel doesnt add value, except for motivating the issue). In the end, the last code example is what I look for: run some function/script that evaluates all reactives.

Comment: Regarding using observers. I'd rather not for two reasons: 1) I would have to rewrite the app (annoying once but if it would solve then so be it) 2) it would change the structure of the app and make all calculations run at eagerly, which might impose other bottlenecks

Comment: Regardless, thank you for the attempt at finding a solution!

Comment: Usually it would be sufficient to set `suspendWhenHidden = FALSE` for those plots via `outputOptions()`. However, this does [not seem to work with shiny's modules](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1731).

Comment: I filed a related issue [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3753).

Comment: Btw. are you aware of the fact, that you can use `bindCache()` along with with `renderPlot()`? Or directly use `renderCachedPlot`.

Comment: These are all valuable comments. Thanks for them. The problem is that we have a mixture of values to display via boxes as well as charts in multiple nested modules. Also I dont see how using bindCache allows me to prefill the cache so that the first interaction is faster.

Answer (score 0):

One partial solution that I am using so far is to define a list of all ids I want to visit and then evaluate the values with the (undocumented) `shiny:::flushReact()` like so:

```
ids <- c("ui1", "ui2")
for (id in ids) {
  testServer(mod_server, args = list(id = id), {
    shiny:::flushReact()
  })
}
#> [1] "Evaluating Reactive Element in Server id ui1"
#> [1] "Evaluating Reactive Element in Server id ui2"
```